# jquery animate question

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

jquery code

```
$(function(){
            $('#switcher1').click(function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({left:'35px'},800);
            });
        });
```

Hey everybody, this code slides #switcher1 at 35px to the right. I have question, how i can make that #switcher1 on one more click slides back to the original position ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$('#switcher1').toggle(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({left:'35px'},800);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({left:'0px'},800);
});
```

Comment: Yeap, It works, but there should be '0' instead of '-35px' :)
Thank you )